# Finding postfix path

Tags: linux, email, ubuntu

Using my linux machine, I downloaded postfix to receive and send mail. I can send external mail, but anything internal does not send. My local mail is being delivered to the file /home/original/Maildir/new, but my mail program checks the path /var/mail/original for received mail. Any email send is not found because it is looking in the wrong path file. I'm a newbie with linux and ubuntu and have no clue how to fix this. What file contains mail path files and what line do I change to fix where postfix looks for incoming mail? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

/home/original/Maildir/new is the "new" Maildir naming convention, while /var/mail/original is the old and traditional Unix one. You have to choose one and stick with it for all your programs. For Postfix, this is configured in /etc/postfix/main.conf :

New:

```
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

Old :

(Nothing to do, it is Postfix default)

See http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html section "MAIL DELIVERY"